# "ipmitool chassis bootdev" command fails with command disabled

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

On a *Lenovo System x3550 M5*, running ipmitool chassis bootdev command fails with

*Set Chassis Boot Parameter 4 failed: Cannot execute command, command disabled*

eg:

```
% ipmitool chassis bootdev pxe options=efiboot 
Set Chassis Boot Parameter 4 failed: Cannot execute command, command disabled
% ipmitool chassis bootdev disk
Set Chassis Boot Parameter 4 failed: Cannot execute command, command disabled
```

any suggestion on how to enable the command back ?

Answer (score 0):

Reset the management controller

`% ipmitool mc reset cold`